# where am i doing wrong? JS

Tags: javascript

I am newbie at the Javascript and i just trying to learning functions it's a little bit hard but i do my best :). I am doing a function to calculate bmi like this ;

```js
let calculateWeight = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your weight", ))

let calculateHeight = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your height?"))

function calculateBmi(weight, height) {
  let bmi = weight / (height * height)
  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    console.log("You are underweight")
  } else if (bmi > 18.6) {
    console.log("You are normal weight")
  } else if (bmi > 25) {
    console.log("you are overweigh")
  }

  return bmi;


}
console.log(calculateBmi(calculateWeight, calculateHeight))
```

if i enter my values 72 weight and 1.80 kilos it says you are normal weight yeah it's correct but whenever i enter my values >25 it's says again you are normal weight where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: the last condition never runs as the second condition can handle all cases where bmi > 18.6 (including bmi >25) 

You need to restrict the second condition to be `bmi > 18.6 && bmi <= 25`

Answer (score 1):

> but whenever i enter my values >25 it's says again you are normal weight

Because there's no value greater than `25` which doesn't satisfy this condition:

```
} else if (bmi > 18.6) {
```

It sounds like you just want the first and third conditions, and everything else is "normal":

```
if (bmi < 18.5) {
  console.log("You are underweight")
} else if (bmi > 25) {
  console.log("you are overweigh")
} else {
  console.log("You are normal weight")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each step in the switch is evaluated in order, and the first one that's met will execute.

In this case, any value above 18.6 will hit your second case.  To get it to pass by yo the third case, you need an upper limit on the value.

```js
...
else if (bmi>18.6 && bmi <= 25){
...
```

Comment: ahh! i got it now... Thank you so much it's really help me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is just a small issue in your calculateBmi function.

See, whenever Bmi is coming greater than 25, the second condition in your else if ladder gets satisfied and "You are normal weight" gets printed in the console.

Fix condition as done below, and your issue will be fixed.

```js
let calculateWeight = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your weight"))

let calculateHeight = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your height?"))

function calculateBmi (weight , height){
    let bmi = weight / (height * height)
    if(bmi < 18.5){
        console.log("You are underweight")
    }else if (bmi>18.6 && bmi<=25){
        console.log("You are normal weight")
    }else if (bmi>25){
        console.log("you are overweigh")
    }
     
    return bmi ;
     
    
} 
console.log(calculateBmi(calculateWeight, calculateHeight))
```